# iterate through two custom arrays and set values if variables are equal Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, foreach, iteration

I have an easy question that is also hard at the same time. I have two separate structs (this can also work for classes):

```
struct FBTweet {
    var tweetId: Int? //set
    var tweetText: String?  //set
}
```

and

```
struct Status {
    var statusId: Int? //set
    var statusText: String? //no value
    }
```

I have an array of both structs `var fbTweetArray: [FBTweet] = []` and `var statusArray: [Status] = []`

I have set every variable in to a certain value in each index in fbTweetArray but I only set the `.statusId` variable in each index for statusArray. For every `statusArray.statusId` value in statusArray, there is only one `fbTweetArray.tweetId` that has the same exact Int value. I am trying to make is so that if these two variables are the same then I should set set 
`statusArray.statusText` to whatever `fbTweetarray.tweetText` is. So for example only `fbTweetArray[1].tweetid = 2346` and `statusArray[4].statusId = 2346` have 2346 as their value. There for if `fbTweetArray[1].tweetText = "hello friend"` then `statusArray[4].statusText` needs to be set to "hello friend".

So far I have

```
func testWhat () {

    var fbTweetArray: [FBTweet] = []
    var statusArray: [Status] = []

    for  fbTweet in fbTweetArray {
        for var status in statusArray {
            if (status.statusId == fbTweet.tweetId ) {
                status.statusText = fbTweet.tweetText
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how do I set the `for var status` in the for loop back into the statusArray since it is now a var and is different than one of the indexes in `var statusArray: [Status] = []`

Comment: _"Iterate through both arrays, compare the .tweetId and .statusId values and then set the text variables correctly"_ This is the answer? Or are you looking for a simpler one?

Comment: How exactly do i do that in Swift, code-wise @RakeshaShastri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need only one `for`/`forEach` loop to achieve what you want:

```
var fbTweetArray: [FBTweet] = [
    FBTweet(tweetId: 1, tweetText: "1"),
    FBTweet(tweetId: 2, tweetText: "2"),
    FBTweet(tweetId: 3, tweetText: "3")
]

var statusArray: [Status] = [
    Status(statusId: 2, statusText: nil),
    Status(statusId: 1, statusText: nil),
    Status(statusId: 3, statusText: nil)
]

fbTweetArray.forEach { tweet in
    if let index = statusArray.index(where: { $0.statusId == tweet.tweetId }) {
        statusArray[index].statusText = tweet.tweetText
    }
}

print(statusArray.map { $0.statusText }) // [Optional("2"), Optional("1"), Optional("3")]
```

Note, that your `id`s in both structures can be `nil`. To handle this situation (if both id is nil - objects are not equal) you can write custom `==` func:

```
struct Status {
    var statusId: Int? //set
    var statusText: String? //no value

    static func == (lhs: Status, rhs: FBTweet) -> Bool {
        guard let lhsId = lhs.statusId, let rhsId = rhs.tweetId else { return false }
        return lhsId == rhsId
    }
}

...

// rewrite .index(where: ) in if condition
if let index = statusArray.index(where: { $0 == tweet }) { ... }
```

---

Also, there is some pro-tip. If you adopt your structs to `Hashable` protocol, you will be able to place `FBTweet`s and `Status`es into `Set` structure. The benefits of that:

> If you instead store those objects in a set, you can theoretically
>   find any one of them in constant time (O(1)) — that is, a lookup on a
>   set with 10 elements takes the same amount of time as a lookup on a
>   set with 10,000.

You can find more in-depth info about it in a new great [article by NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/hashable/).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is interesting only if both the arrays are not ordered.

To find the element from fbTweet array, you can sort it and employ binary search.
Then enumerate status array and find the fbTweet object with the same identifier and modify the status object. It needs to be saved again in the array as structs get copied on write.

```
extension Array where Element == FBTweet {
    func binarySearchFBTweetWith(_ id:Int) -> FBTweet? {
        var range = 0..<self.count
        while range.startIndex < range.endIndex {
            let midIndex = range.startIndex + (range.endIndex - range.startIndex) / 2
            guard let tweetId = self[midIndex].tweetId else {
                continue
            }
            if tweetId == id {
                return self[midIndex]
            } else if tweetId < id {
                range = midIndex+1..<range.endIndex
            } else {
                range = range.startIndex..<midIndex
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

fbTweetArray.sort{($0.tweetId ?? 0) < ($1.tweetId ?? 0)}
for (index, status) in statusArray.enumerated() {
    guard let statusId = status.statusId else {continue}
    guard let fbTweet = fbTweetArray.binarySearchFBTweetWith(statusId) else {continue}
    var status = status
    status.statusText = fbTweet.tweetText
    statusArray[index] = status
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be use dictionaries instead of arrays, for better performance and easier implementation (in this case). You can easily get the array of keys and values later If you need.

In this case, the Id would be the Key of the dictionary, and the text the value.